# Modifying UIButtons layer depending on state

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, calayer, rounded-corners

I have a background UI Image which is shown whenever i touch a UIButton:

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have also modified the layer of the uibutton to give a rounded corner

```
[btn.layer setCornerRadius:10];
```

This works but the corner radius is not being used for the background image. I can access the image at

```
[btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlEventTouchDown]
```

but as this is an UIImage it will not have a CA Layer

What I want is for the background image to also be supported by the CALayer or at the very least should support rounded corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to set `masksToBounds` to YES:

```
btn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I knew I must have forgotten something, thanks so much. The points go to you :)